# Is it possible to render raw variable brackets in twig within translation tags

Tags: php, symfony, twig

We're looking for a new way to create multi language email templates. We got the idea to use inky in twig to create clean email HTML and render translations. The problem is that we have Sendgrid (handlebars) that renders variables the same way as twig.

Is there a solution to create a translation in twig having the {{ }} intact. We don't want to translate around the brackets because that could not be compatible with the language its spelling.

**example**

```
{% trans %}I am a {{ job }}{% endtrans %}
```

gives the following error:

> A message inside a trans tag must be a simple text.

Comment: Did you try to escape the brackets, like `\{\{ job }}`

Comment: That prints I am a \{\{ job \}\}. I could replace the \{\{ into {{ after redering but I try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply fix this by using the filter option:

```
{{ 'i am {{ job }}'| trans({},'domain') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [verbatim](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/verbatim.html) tag to escape twig delimiters (or `raw` in twig 1 and 2).

> The verbatim tag marks sections as being raw text that should not be parsed.

```
{% trans %}
    {% verbatim %}
        I am a {{ job }}
    {% endverbatim %}
{% endtrans %}
```

Another simple way would be to just output your twig delimiters as a string :

```
{% trans %}I am a {{ '{{' }} job {{ '}}' }}{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: Tried these before and they give the same error: A message inside a trans tag must be a simple text.

Comment: What is your twig version ?

Comment: 3.4. If a previous version work I'd like to know because I have no problem with downgrading.